# Aura Component with LWC: Failed to resolve import

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, deployment

We are trying to deploy an Aura component that houses an LWC that utilizes templates with the `return` on the `render()` method. The component works fine by itself but when we add it to an aura component we get:

> LWC1011: Failed to resolve import "./forms/ThisForm/Form.html"

The file exists 100% and as I said works fine by itself but we need to put it in an aura component to handle custom navigation.

aura:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
    <c:formSheet formName="myForm" />
</aura:component>
```

lwc JS:

```
import myForm from './forms/specialForm/myForm.html';
import defaultTemplate from './forms/default.html';

export default class FormSheet extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api formName;
    render(){
        switch(this.formName) {
            case 'myForm': {
                return myForm;
            }
            default:
                return defaultTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with all lowercase folder and file names?

Comment: @PhilW still didn't work with all lower case. I think somehow the aura component can't reach into the sub-sub-directory

Comment: But it is the LWC that does this reaching-in, right?

Comment: I suggest you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/317006/edit) your question to add actual technical detail, at least enough to allow others to try reproducing the issue. As it stands, there's no detail so unless someone has seen exactly the same issue before you're unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks, @PhilW. I added a few technical components. Let me know if anything else might help.

Comment: Please add how this.formName is controlled. I assume this would be an API property set by the Aura component?

Comment: We moved the files to the `./forms` directory with the naming `./forms/specialFormmyForm.html` and it worked.

Comment: I suggest you add your own answer so folks can see that easily in future.

Answer (score 1):

We moved the files to the `./forms` directory with the naming `./forms/specialFormmyForm.html` and it worked. So it appears to be a directory related issue.

I believe this will only be an issue for Aura components hosting LWC components as the component works standalone without issue.

After testing with an LWC hosting the LWC, it works. So it does appear to be Aura hosting the LWC related.